# Beans inside beans in SpringFramework?

Tags: java, spring

There are some situations, where beans can be regarded as entities, similar to bean containers or configurations.

For example, GUI window can contain some controls. Here, both windows and it's controls are beans.

Does SpringFramework provide some specific patterns to implement this situation? For example, may be it is ok to implement [`BeanFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) or use [`@Component`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) annotation for this?

Or the main guidance is still initialize everything from separate configuation and not mix it with real objects?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get your point clearly but what I understood is you are trying to have a bean inside a bean. If I understood correctly the you can use the annotation `@Bean` over a component inside any bean class which is decorated with any of the following annotation - `@Controller`, `@RestController`, `@Configuration`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Component`.

A method onto which you decorate `@Bean` should return an object that can qualify to register as a bean.

Now you can inject (using `@Autowired`) this registered bean.